# Connecting to a UltraVNC server in one click

Tags: windows-7, automation, ultravnc

I have to following setup on two Win7 machines connected over LAN:

UltraVNC Server <---- UltraVNC Viewer

Since I'm only interested into connecting always to the same server, I was wondering if it is possible to start the viewer and connect to the server with only one-click.

```
Start Viewer + Connect + Enter Password (three steps)
```

Since I've already figured out that I can automate the last step with the -password argument, I'm down to two steps:

```
Start Viewer + Connect (two steps)
```

How can I tell the UltraVNC viewer to automatically connect?

Comment: This might help http://www.uvnc.com/products/uvnc-sc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new shortcut, [then following the documentation](http://www.uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-viewer/52-ultravnc-viewer-commandline-parameters.html) to see what to put into it. You'll find this example about halfway down the page:

```
"%programfiles%\ultravnc\vncviewer.exe" -autoreconnect 30 -connect hostname::5900 -quickoption 3
```

Substitute `hostname` for the machine you're after.

Note that the documentation doesn't seem to be clear on how to specify a `host` and a `port`. The example is `host::port` but I suspect it's actually `host:port`.

Comment: thx! The "-connect" argument was what I was looking for.

Comment: And I added credentials to connect on one click  "-user <username> -password <password>"

Answer (score 0):

Sample resolution:

```
start vncviewer -connect 192.168.50.40 -password 8088
```

Password used: 8088 (sample)
IP: 192.168.50.40 (sample)